# Common arguments graphQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, graphql

I'm trying to implement two mutations in graphql-ruby - one for creation of a resource, and one for editing. In most scenarios, they both take the exact same parameters from the client, so I want to avoid duplicating the mutations and try and have the arguments specified in a reusable class/module.

I'm using graphql-ruby 1.8 and the new class based API, and have started with this:

```
class Mutations::ApplicationMutation < GraphQL::Schema::Mutation
  ... common to every mutation ...
end

class Mutations::CreateResourceMutation < Mutations::ApplicationMutation
  argument :name, String, required: true
  argument :description, String
  argument :create_only_field, String
end

class Mutations::UpdateResourceMutation < Mutations::ApplicationMutation
  argument :name, String, required: true
  argument :description, String
  argument :update_only_field, String
end
```

In this basic example, the `name` and `description` attributes are the same in both mutations. I've extracted the resolver out into another class so that is reusable, but I'm not sure the best way to tackle the arguments.

I imagine an ActiveSupport::Concern would work, but it doesn't feel right or the way I think it should work for this, but I'm very new to GraphQL in general so have no idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can suggest a nice solution creating a complex argument and use in two mutations.
Here is the code

```
# graphql/inputs/resource_input.rb

Inputs::ResourceInput = GraphQL::InputObjectType.define do
  name 'ResourceInput'
  description 'An input object representing arguments for a user'

  argument :name, String, required: true
  argument :description, String
  argument :create_only_field, String
  argument :update_only_field, String
end
```

and in mutations you can just use

```
 argument :resourceInput, Inputs::ResourceInput, "the resource complex input"
```

Hope this will help you to avoid dupes

Comment: Sorry I completely missed this. Exactly what I ended up doing :)